# How to point LLVM_CONFIG environment variable to the path for llvm-config

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, numba

I am trying to install `numba` on an OS X Mountain Lion. I had tried the `pip install` way but didn't work, so I have downloaded from the GIT respositories the zip files. When trying to install numba I realized that I need `LLVM` first.

I downloaded and unpacked `llvm` into the `Download` folder. The README instructions are: "If your LLVM is installed in a non-standard location, first point the `LLVM_CONFIG` environment variable to the path of the corresponding `llvm-config` executable."; a message compatible with the RunTimeError I get when running the `python setup.py install` command.

My problem is that I don't understand what to do in order to make the `LLVM_CONFIG` environment variable to point to the corresponding `llvm-config` executable.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 14):

The actual location is reported by brew.  For me it was:

```
==> Caveats
LLVM executables are installed in /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin.
Extra tools are installed in /usr/local/opt/llvm/share/llvm.
```

Then, e.g.:

```
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/llvm-config pip install numba
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I needed to install llvm first. My problem was that I was installing LLVMLITE not LLVM.

So `brew install llvm` and then locating llvm-config in the `Cellar` directory solved my problem.

Comment: For others, note that you have to `export` the LLVM_CONFIG var, with the user that runs the install (maybe root).